connecting to leader from a validator with small stake
good day, I have trawled the internet to try to get this info, no luck..
if we are running an RPC server and are using jito bundles to get our transactions through , they are pretty consistently fast (I assume they use stake weighted QoS validators). Would we have more success if we ran our own RPC and validator, with a small amount of staked sol , and just tipped the leader directly ?
